# Inverse interpolation function: find x value by y value

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a question about MATLAB interpolation
Picture is plotting data.
x axis is t
y axis is rpmm

I want to find x value when I input y value.
but i meet error message

in case of finding y value, i can find y value when i input x value
but not x value

[image: plot of x and y]

```
interp1(t,rpmm,30)

ans =

719.9229

interp1(rpmm,t,1200)

Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors are not strictly monotonic increasing.

Error in interp1 (line 183)
    F = griddedInterpolant(X,V,method);
```

Comment: how about ["inverse" INTERP1: findX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23860-single-variable-linear-level-finding---inverse--interp1---findx)

Comment: When you input the `y` value `2500`, which `x` are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 1):

This error will occur if you have two or more identical values in `rpmm`. In this case `interp1` cannot know which is the correct value to map from values in `rpmm` to values of `t`. One way you could solve this is by adding a small jitter to your `rpmm` value as in:

```
interp1(rpmm+1e-10*randn(size(rpmm)),t,1200)
```

However, this may not be desirable behaviour and if you do indeed have two identical values in `rpmm`, you should try to understand what you actually mean to interpolate in such an ambiguous case.

**Update**
Your updated question with the plot confirms this: in the interval `20 < t < 25` your `rpmm` has the same value (~2500). So when mapping from an `rpmm` of 2500 what `t` should `interp1` return? There is no correct answer. Similarly for `t > 35`, `rpmm` seems to reach an asymptote so its values may become identical due to representation precision.

However, since you're interested in the `t` for an `rpmm` of 1200, the answer *is* well defined in that interval, so you could exclude the ambiguous intervals from the interpolation as in:

```
interp1(rpmm(t>25&t<35),t(t>25&t<35),1200)
```